# requiresDependencyResolution in a multi-module project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, multi-module

If you want to run a Maven goal that has `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE` in its `@Mojo` annotation, i.e. requires that all dependencies are resolved before it runs, you face a problem in a multi-module project.

If one module references another, this other module does not exist (when you start the goal with `plugin:some-goal` on the parent or child), and the resolution fails.

How should I use such a Maven plugin in the context of a multi-module project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `requiresDependencyCollection` wherever possible because it does not require the other module to be built.